# How can I create halftone effects in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

How can I create this effect in Photoshop? It basically is square dots that come closer together and are bigger where the image is darker.

[image: Halftone effect]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That method is called "halftoning", and there is a tutorial for doing it in Photoshop [here](http://www.blueglass.com/blog/halftone-and-bitmap-effects-photoshop-tutorial/).